# java.io.IOException: File Not Found

Tags: java, spring

I have uploaded a `MultipartFile` which is a video, and am trying to use capture a frame of it using some code. However, when it tries to open the file, it always gives the error `java.io.IOException: File Not Found`.

First I extract the multipart file to a normal file like so:

```
File convertedFile = new File(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
multipartFile.transferTo(convertedFile);
```

Then I set the file name of the video to the code to capture the frame like this:

```
"file://" + convertedFile.getName()
```

then it fails when it tries to create a URL out of the file name:

```
new URL(_videoFilename));
```

How can I make it find the file?

Comment: Try to use convertedFile.toURI().toURL() to create an URL from your File

Comment: Note that according to the [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--), `MultiPartFile#getOriginalFileName` *[...] may contain path information depending on the browser used, but it typically will not with any other than Opera.*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with `MultipartFile` but you can find this in the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)

> The file contents **are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk**.
>   In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a
>   session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary
>   storages will be cleared at the end of request processing.

Therefore, you certainly have to use`transferTo(File dest)` to be able to handle your file on a determined place.